# Why do App store connect operation errors ITMS-90685 and ITMS-90680 happen?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect, swift-package-manager

The errors:

ITMS-90685: CFBundleIdentifierCollision. There is more than one bundle with the CFBundleIdentifier value `com.[companyName].[className]` under the iOS application `[myAppName].app`

ITMS-90680: invalid directory. The bundle `Payload/[myAppName].app/Plugins/[myFramework].framework` is not contained in a correctly named directory. It should be under "Frameworks"

Background info: Happens on the last part of uploading in Xcode. I'm using SPM and linking this framework into my app's target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ITMS-90685:
Have you already submitted a ios app under this name before? It might be the case that you reused the id?  If this is not the case, make sure your compnyName is unique.

ITMS-90680:
you need to have your framework under the Framework directory, and not the Plugins directory.

Answer (score 0):

Change your app bundle (ID) and try again